# o Use a script to populate the records in the table for start date 2017-01-01 and end date 2019-12-01

Tags: mysql, date

I want to use a script to populate the records in the table for start date 2017-01-01 and end date 2019-12-01

The date counter should start at 10 and increment for every record

I have a table called DaysForTenYears MH
with coloumns:
ID (Identity)
Date (Date)
DateCounter (int)

How would I populate those records?

Comment: [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/) and [SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-reference) are different software packages produced by different companies. Even if both of them implement SQL, they extend it in different ways and sometimes they use different syntax conventions that render the queries incompatible between them. Please use only the tags that match the software you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive CTE query on SQL Server and create your own dates table data. You will find a sample [SQL dates table query](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-server-dates-table-using-tsql-cte-calendar-table.aspx) at referenced tutorial

Here is how you can implement it for 10 days periods

```
WITH CTE_DatesTable
AS
(
  SELECT CAST('20170101' as date) AS [date]
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATEADD(dd, 10, [date])
  FROM CTE_DatesTable
  WHERE DATEADD(dd, 10, [date]) <= '20191201'
)
SELECT [date] FROM CTE_DatesTable
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

I hope it helps,